# Jquery Uploadify images multiple instance and call each instance completion of previous one

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, uploadify

I am using Jquery Uploadify for images upload with PHP, here i have multiple instances of  uploadify and and each instance is uploading images in different folders.

I want to second instance of uploadify will start uploading images only after first instance of uploadify uploaded selected image.

$('#listing_image').uploadifySettings('folder','listing_image_TempImage');
            $('#listing_image').uploadifyUpload();
            $('#listing_image1').uploadifySettings('folder','listing_image1_TempImage');
            $('#listing_image1').uploadifyUpload();

i.e  'listing_image1' will get call when processing of 'listing_image' will be completed.
How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant add a comment to you'r answer yet. So i'm writing it here instead.

Try to make one upload work by using this (make sure the links point's to the correct locations):

```
$('#listing_image').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : 'uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : 'uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : 'cancel.png',
    'folder'    : '/listing_image_TempImage',
    onComplete: function(){ 
        // Do oncomplete stuff. 
    }
});
```

When you can get that to work, then you should be able to make this work.

```
var uploads = [2,4,5]; // Only number 2,4 and 5
var numberofuploads = uploads.length; // How many is that?
var folderlist = [0, '/folder1', '/folder2', '/folder3', '/folder4', '/folder5', '/folder6']; // List of folders to upload to
var listingimageslist = [0, '#listing_image1', '#listing_image2', '#listing_image3', '#listing_image4', '#listing_image5', '#listing_image6']; // List of form selectors. 

var folder = folderlist[uploads[0]]; // What folder should this form upload to
var listingimages = listingimageslist[uploads[0]]; // With what selector can the form be found?
if (numberofuploads > 1)
{
    var next = 1; // What upload to initiate after this one?
}
initUpload(listingimages,folder); // make the upload thing work. 


function initUpload(e,folder)
{
    $(e).uploadify({
        'folder'    : folder,
        'uploader'  : 'uploadify.swf',
        'script'    : 'uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg' : 'cancel.png',
        onComplete: function(){ 
            var folder = folderlist[uploads[next]];
            var listingimages = listingimageslist[uploads[next]];
            next++
            if (numberofuploads != next)
            {
                initUpload(listingimages,folder);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

I didn't test the code, but you should be able to make it work if you know a bit of javascript.

Remenber to have all your jQuery code in a $(document).ready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // Insert code here
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Webbies but here i got one problem.... i checked for first two instances but this code is not uplaoding images for first 2 instances... $('#listing_image').uploadify({ 'folder' : '/listing_image_TempImage', onComplete: function(){ $('#listing_image1').uploadify({ 'folder' : '/listing_image_TempImage' }); } });

Comment: Try to make just one work, using the first snippet of code i provided in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a "callback" function, that fires when the first upload is completed.

```
$('#listing_image').uploadify({
 'folder'    : '/listing_image_TempImage',
 onComplete: function(){ 
  $('#listing_image1').uploadify({
   'folder'    : '/listing_image_TempImage'
  });
 }
});
```

With 6 (one after the other) uploads:

```
$('#listing_image').uploadify({
    'folder'    : '/listing_image_TempImage',
    onComplete: function(){ 
        $('#listing_image1').uploadify({
            'folder'    : '/listing_image_TempImage1',
            onComplete: function(){ 
                $('#listing_image2').uploadify({
                    'folder'    : '/listing_image_TempImage2',
                    onComplete: function(){ 
                        $('#listing_image3').uploadify({
                            'folder'    : '/listing_image_TempImage3',
                            onComplete: function(){ 
                                $('#listing_image4').uploadify({
                                    'folder'    : '/listing_image_TempImage4',
                                    onComplete: function(){ 
                                        $('#listing_image5').uploadify({
                                            'folder'    : '/listing_image_TempImage5'   
                                        });
                                    }   
                                });
                            }           
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I assume that it's [this uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com) you are talking about.

For at full list of available callbacks, [look in the docs](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/).

Comment: Thanks for answer.
yes, i am talking about same uplaodify...here i have 6 instances of uploadify so how i can implement "callback" for all 6 instances??? 

you example will work for only 2 instances.

Comment: You are talking about having them all one after the other. So the fifth will only run after the fourth is complete?

Comment: and it might be user selected only 2nd, 4rd and 5th instances of uploadify so how we can handle this behavior ?

Comment: i just added with 6, on after the other uploads. 

but if the user can select which uploads he want, that's a bit more tricky. 
You need some variables. 
I'll make a proff of concept, that you can modify, and post a new answer when i got it.

Comment: Thank you very much Webbies but here i got one problem.... i checked for first two instances but this code is not uplaoding images for first 2 instances... $('#listing_image').uploadify({
 'folder'    : '/listing_image_TempImage',
 onComplete: function(){ 
  $('#listing_image1').uploadify({
   'folder'    : '/listing_image_TempImage'
  });
 }
});

Answer (score 0):

If you use sessions, script execution is going to be delayed on server side so each upload will get processed one after another anyway.

Comment: Hi Pekka, actually now requirement is changed...Now we have 6 instances of Uploadify and each instance will have fixed folder where images will upload so here i want second instance of uplaodify will call only when processing first instance of uploadify completed.    

Given code is not uplaoding images 

$('#listing_image').uploadify({
 'folder'    : '/listing_image_TempImage',
 onComplete: function(){ 
  $('#listing_image1').uploadify({
   'folder'    : '/listing_image_TempImage'
  });
 }
});